# C language, giving value to char in an if-else statement?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am trying to use define like this

```
`printf ("1st Account:");
scanf("%i",&AN1);
printf ("Value of 1st Account:");
scanf("%f",&VAN1);
printf ("2nd Account:");
scanf("%i",&AN2);
printf ("Value of 2nd Account:");
scanf("%f",&VAN2);
system("pause");
system("cls");
if (AN1==101)
#define CAN1 "Cash"
else if (AN1==102)
#define CAN1 "Accounts Receivable"
else if (AN1==104)
#define CAN1 "Notes Receivable"`
```

and so on

Obviously, it didn't work since define is for the whole program and is not read only within the if statement.

Does anyone know how to make it work?
I need to display it later so like so

```
`printf ("Your 1st account name is: %s with the value of %.2f.\n",CAN1,VAN1);
printf ("Your 2nd account name is: %s with the value of %.2f.\n",CAN2,VAN2);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use variable instead of define:

```
 const char *can1 ="unknown";

 if (AN1==101)
    can1 = "Cash";
else if (AN1==102)
     can1 = "Accounts Receivable";
else if (AN1==104)
    can1 = "Notes Receivable";
```

define is processed in compile time while your value is only known in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly observed, `#define` statements and preprocessor directives in general are evaluated before compile time. The preprocessor processes the file, outputs the preprocessed one, and passes it to the compiler, which eventually generates object files and/or executables.
The preprocessor has no notion of scopes, braces, grammar, or language constructs. It just parses the source file, substitutes macro occurrences, and performs other meta-stuff.

As a replacement, you can use string literals:

```
const char* ptr;

if (that)
    ptr = "that";
else
    ptr = "else";
```

String literals cannot go out of scope because they exist for the whole runtime of the program; they are usually stored within the very core image of the executable.

Answer (score 1):

## define is handled in preprocessing, at compile time. You can't conditionally define things at runtime.

You can assign constants to a pointer though:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

char *can1;
int an1 = 0;

if (an1 == 0) 
    can1 = "Cash";
else if (an1 == 102)
    can1 = "Accounts Receivable";
else if (an1 == 104)
    can1 = "Notes Receivable";

printf("%s\n", can1);
}
```